# Why is not $\eta(\tau+1)=\eta(\tau)$ although $\Delta(\tau+1)=\Delta(\tau)$

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I am confused with why is not $\eta(\tau+1)=\eta(\tau)$ although $\Delta(\tau+1)=\Delta(\tau)$ and one can define $\eta=\Delta^{1/24}$. Hope this is not a very stupid question. Whereas $\Delta$ is the Discriminant modular form and $\eta$ is the dedekind eta function

Comment: Are you kidding ? $\eta(\tau) = e^{2i\pi  \tau/24} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-e^{2 i \pi n  \tau})$ thus $\eta(\tau+1) =e^{2i\pi ( \tau+1)/24} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-e^{2 i\pi n (\tau+1)}) = e^{2i \pi /24}\eta(\tau)$

Comment: $\eta(\tau+1) = e^{2i \pi /24} \eta(\tau)$ implies $\eta(\tau+1)^{24} =  \eta(\tau)^{24}$

Comment: Yes I know, but $\eta=\Delta^{1/24}$ and $\Delta(\tau+1)=\Delta(\tau)$ obviously does not imply that $\eta(\tau+1)=\eta(\tau)$ and that is what my question was about.

Comment: It is not true that $\eta(\tau) = \Delta(\tau)^{1/24}$. What is true is that there is a branch of $z \mapsto z^{1/24}$ such that for $\tau$ close to $a, \eta(a) \ne 0$ : $\eta(\tau) = \Delta(\tau)^{1/24}$, but the branch isn't the same when moving with $\tau$. See how it works with $e^{2i \pi \tau/24} = (e^{2i \pi \tau})^{1/24}$

Answer (score 4):

The equation $a^n=b^n$ does not imply $a=b$, it only implies $a=\xi b$ for some $n$th root of unity $\xi$.

In particular, $\Delta(\tau+1)=\Delta(\tau)$, or in other words $\eta(\tau+1)^{24}=\eta(\tau)^{24}$, must then imply that $\eta(\tau+1)=\xi\,\eta(\tau)$ where $\xi$ is some $24$th root of unity (note $\xi$ cannot depend on $\tau$ since the $24$th roots of unity are a discrete set). It just so happens that $\xi=\exp(2\pi i/24)$.

The "definition" $\eta=\Delta^{1/24}$ is ambiguous because it doesn't say which $24$th root to extract, and it seems to imply that which $24$th root is being chosen is independent of $\tau$, which is false.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me. Thank you :)